# Problem with sudo apt update What should I do with this?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

When I wrote in terminal "sudo apt update" I saw this and I don't know what should I do. Can you help me?

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have added repositories for applications to your apt sources.list file. They have been disabled and will have no effect. All this means is those applications will not be updated from those repositories.

At some stage you must have attempted to install [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and Wine from the Ubuntu Wine Team. Both of these repositories look like they have been archived and are no longer in use.

Answer (score 1):

What it's saying is that the repos listed there will be ignored regarding updates. They're third party repos so your regular system updates should work just fine. You could try disabling the third party repos it has listed there, or checking to see if there's been some kind of change that would require you to remove and re-add them.

There's a few reasons for a repo to not have a release file. A common one is when you're using an older version of Ubuntu that those developers no longer support.

Comment: How can I disable the third party repos it has listed there or check if there is been some kind of change that would require me to remove and re-add them? I don't use terminal often and I don't know how to use it more professional.

Comment: They should be listed in the "sources" area of the graphical application labeled "Software and Sources".